Uncertainty regarding validity of contract after tiny mistake
I recently accepted a new job, but when signing the contract, I accidentally wrote down the wrong signing date. I signed in September but am due to start in July, so I accidentally wrote down July. The process happened through DocuSign, and I now have an electronically signed version of the deed, with a wrong date. I let them know of my mistake and offered to sign a new version, however they just sent me an amended PDF with July crossed out and September inserted, with person making the amendment also signing their initials next to the change. However, this new PDF is no longer electronically signed, since it has been tampered with, and all electronic signatures on the document turned into mere pictures. I now basically only have a wrong electronically signed copy, and a correct not electronically signed copy.
Do I still have a valid contract? I am concerned due to the fact that this contract will later be  fundamental to me obtaining my work visa, and ultimately living (legally) in the UK.

Very likely, yes. Court is not stupid. What they want see, that you accepted and signed a contract with identifiable parameters. Note, sending yet another contract might have ended you having two independent contract with same content but with different starting date. There are infinite ways to increase chaos, I suggest to not do :-)

Is it a valid contract?
Yes. All that matters is that each side gave up something of value in the contract ("consideration"), you each intended to be legally bound ("intention"), and you each agreed to the terms of the contract ("agreement").
When you signed it, you intended to be legally bound (or at least that will be the presumption), and you agreed to the terms. Writing the wrong date doesn't change those facts. In fact, signatures and dates aren't even necessary components of most contracts (there are exceptions but they don't apply here). You can agree a contract verbally or through conduct.
Is it good evidence of a valid contract?
Probably, but possibly not. Having a valid contract isn't the same thing as being able to prove that you have a valid contract. It's possible that someone (e.g. the Home Office, or a court) might not accept a document with the wrong date as evidence of the contract. However, the document isn't the only evidence. Other items can also be evidence of there being a valid contract (e.g. copies of email exchanges were the signatures were organised, a copy of the amended contract, etc.). Ultimately, what matters is that a court can be convinced, on the balance of probabilities (i.e. with greater than 50% likelihood) that there was a contract.
We can't give legal advice on this site so you'll have to decide for yourself (or ask a lawyer) whether your document will be good enough for your future needs.
Caveat
You refer in your question at one point to "the deed". A deed is a special type of contract with its own rules. I'm assuming that you made a mistake here and that it isn't in fact a deed.
